# AWS: JavaScript ajax to show the result of aws lambda function through RestAPI on webpage

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, rest

I am trying to learn AWS. I hosted a simple index.html file on S3, which will take the first and last name from the user and when the user clicks the submit button it will trigger the API and then lambda function to display the full name. My lambda function is working but I am not sure how can I display the result of the lambda function on the web. Thank you so much for your hep and time

Index.html code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>My Serverless Web App</title>
        <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var API_URL = ' ---------';
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#submit").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var fname = $("#fname").val(), lname = $("#lname").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url: API_URL,
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            "fname": fname,
                            "lname": lname,                                             
                        }),
                        
                        success: function(res){
                            $('#form-response').html('OK DONE' + res);          
                            },
                    error: function(){
                        $('#form-response').html('<div class="alert alert-info"role="alert">Oops! Something went wrong ... </div>');
                            }
                });
                
            });
    });
            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <h1>AWS Learning</h1>
            <p>Welcome to my website!<br/>
        </p>
            <label for="fname" class="control-label">First name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" required />
            <label for="lname" class="control-label">Last name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name"/>
            <button  id="submit" type="submit"
            style="background-color:#123020;">Send</button>
        </section>
        
        <p>Your name is: <span id="form-response"></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Lambda function

```
import json
print('Loading function')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
 value1 = event['fname']
 value2 = event['lname']
 result = value1 + ' ' + value2
 return {
 'statusCode': "200",
 'body': json.dumps({"result" : result}),
 'headers': {
  "Content-Type" : "application/json",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
  "Allow" : "GET, OPTIONS, POST",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET, OPTIONS, POST",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "*"
 }
}
```

Comment: you can invoke a function using AWS API or javascript SDK. but note, this is not secure and it is very dangerous to expose AWS access keys from the frontend. my advice don't do it.

check this for reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I did read about that but it is just a simple thing I am trying to do for my learning. I have created REST API but from my code, I have removed the API link. So basically when the user clicked the button it triggers the lambda function and I get the response ok done but not the full name. I want to know how can I achieve that or what code I have to add.